# How to correct this code having XML script for IVR.

Tags: xml, ivr

I want to make an ivr for my office's ippbx including menus and submenus and routing of calls. Please Someone help me to correct this code. I am very puzzled and can not understand how to correct it.

```
<include>
<configuration name="ivr.conf" description="IVR menus">
<menus>
  <menu name="TestingIVR"
     greet-long="say: Welcome to Coral Telecom Limited. We are a leading company in            Telecommunication Services and IP Phone Service Providers"
      greet-short="say: Connecting with us means connecting with world. Hope you enjoyed the   services provided by us."
      invalid-sound="say: The choice you have made is invalid. Please make a right choice and try again."
      exit-sound="say: Thanks for calling us. Hope you will find satisfactory solution from our experts. Good Bye"
      confirm-macro=""
      confirm-key=""
      tts-engine="cepstral"
      tts-voice="david"
      confirm-attempts="3"
      timeout="10000"
      inter-digit-timeout="2000"
      max-failures="3"
      max-timeouts="3"
      digit-len="4">

 <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="execute_extension limit:'hash ivr  in',set:acc_code=cucu,playback:say: Thank you for calling in my office and do not call ever in after hours,system:/home/george/alex/test.sh,bridge:sofia/$${domain}/101@192.168.1.240,hangup inline"/>

      <entry action="menu-exec-app" digits="1" param="bridge sofia/$${domain}/830@192.168.1.240"/>

      <entry action="menu-sub" digits="2" param="demo_ivr_submenu"/>  <!-- demo sub menu -->
      <entry action="menu-top" digits="3"/>    <!-- Repeat this menu -->
      </menu>


      <menu name="demo_ivr_submenu"
      greet-long="say: Welcome to Coral Telecom Limited. We are a leading company in    Telecommunication Services and IP Phone Service Providers"
      greet-short="say: Connecting with us means connecting with world. Hope you enjoyed the services provided by us."
      invalid-sound="say: The choice you have made is invalid. Please make a right choice and try again."
      exit-sound="say: Thanks for calling us. Hope you will find satisfactory solution from our experts. Good Bye"
      timeout="15000"
      max-failures="3">
      <entry action="menu-top" digits="*"/>
      </menu>
  </menus>
      </configuration>
      </include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need `</menus>` for decleration of `<menus>`
Put it after your last `</menu>`, document should be ending like this:

```
</menu>
</menus>
</configuration>
</include>
```

Comment: It is not working after editing as you suggested. Line disconnected if I dial IVR extension.